# Template of template operator for containers not resolved as candidate

Tags: c++

I was trying to define a generic operator for containers as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

namespace test {

template<template <typename...> class _Container,
         typename _Type, typename... _Args>
_Container<_Type,_Args...>
operator+(const _Container<_Type,_Args...>& c1,
          const _Container<_Type,_Args...>& c2)
{
  typedef _Container<_Type,_Args...> container_type;

  assert(c1.size() == c2.size());

  container_type result;

  std::transform(c1.begin(), c1.end(), c2.begin(),
                 std::back_inserter(result), std::plus<_Type>());

  return result;
}

} // test namespace
```

However, GCC 4.9.2 does not try as a candidate for the following test code:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vector;
vector v1, v2;
vector result = v1 + v2;
```

I also tried the above without the parameter pack for the template. Same result.

However, without the namespace declaration, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Similar operators defined by the STL in the `std` namespace are tested as candidates.

The error message is simply:

```
/tmp/file.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/file.cc:28:22: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘vector {aka std::vector<int>}’ and ‘vector {aka std::vector<int>}’)
```

Comment: Works without a hitch on Clang 3.8.0. Could you post the full error message from GCC ? Also try removing reserved identifiers (underscore-capitals) from your function.

Comment: Which reserved identifiers? My eyes must be broken today, I can't see it.

Comment: All identifiers beginning with an underscore and a capital (such as `_Type`) are reserved in all scopes for the implementation.

Comment: I did not even know that. Learn something new everyday. Thanks.

Comment: Works for me on GCC 5.1: http://ideone.com/YilwYq

Comment: [And also works on Coliru's GCC 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d28d9b16d5be283d).

Comment: You need to post a complete example that we can compile ourselves, as this is not reproducible as is.

Comment: Yes, just figured it out... it is because of a namespace declaration. Updating the question...

Comment: Well, that's it : you need `using test::operator+;` to make it visible for overload resolution.

Comment: But why does GCC test canditates like `std::operator+(_CharT, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)`, without having to specific `using std::operator+...` ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: Argument Dependent Lookup. Long story short : these operators are declared in the same namespace as their parameters, so they are automatically brought in for overload resolution.

Comment: Thanks. I've learned quite a few things from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was trying to define a generic operator for containers

uh oh...

Ignoring the ADL issues you will have, there are semantic issues too.

For example, consider:

```
vector<int> a { 1, 2, 3 };
vector<int> b { 4, 5, 6 };

auto c = a + b;   // this won't compile, it's for illustration.
```

Question: What should the operation do?

Some people might think it should model this:

```
auto c = concatenate(a, b);
// c == { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

Others might think it should do as you suggest:

```
auto c = add_elements(a, b);
// c == { 5, 7, 9 }
```

Who's right?

The answer is that it depends on the context of use of the vector. The vector is a primitive type. It carries no information about the use case. There is simply not enough information available to make an informed choice.

Wrapping the vector into a custom type allows you to provide contextual information and describe the actions of operators correctly.

Of course, you will need to define the arithmetic operators explicitly for the type.

In summary:

The standard library does not define arithmetic operators for containers for good reason. For that same reason, neither should you.

As a parting note, even the transform interpretation is not trivial. What should happen if the vectors are of different size?

Comment: I get your point, the choice of `operator+` is not the most judicious. The aim in my particular use case was to provide 'arithmetic addition' of container values, regardless of the actual container implementation. But as you say, `add_elements` would be a more appropriate name. As to your last point, there is an `assert` to cover that case (as it should not happen in my given context).

Comment: "generic operator" was perhaps not the best description of my intent either... :)

Comment: @isedev happy to help. As a rule of thumb, I always start with named functions and in the (extremely rare!) cases where it's appropriate to overload an arithmetic operator, implement the operator in terms of the named function. At least then when I return a year later, I have a clue as to what the operator is supposed to do! :-)